# PHP image wrong mimetype

Tags: php, android-file

I'm uploading images from my Android app to my server. The app uses the android camera intent and upload via PHP script is ok.

I want to verify if the uploaded files are real images, I'm not checking the extension but the mimetype (I suppose this is the best way to do it, tell me if I'm wrong).

I'm using a Slackware Linux Apache server and I'm trying this code:

```
....
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, '/etc/httpd/magic');
....
fwrite($fp, finfo_file($finfo, "file.jpg"));
....
```

But I'm getting "application/octet-stream; charset=binary" instead  of  "image/jpeg; charset=binary" which is given from "file -i file.jpg" (shell command).

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); instead of the other line. I think the default magic file is not the same that I was specifing.

Comment: I hope so! In 2 days a lot of stuff happens LOL!

Answer (score 0):

As refered on [www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php):

```
<?php

function is_jpg($fullpathtoimage){
    if(file_exists($fullpathtoimage)){
        exec("/usr/bin/identify -format %m $fullpathtoimage",$out);
        //using system() echos STDOUT automatically
        if(!empty($out)){
            //identify returns an empty result to php
            //if the file is not an image

            if($out == 'JPEG'){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: well, I wouldn't want to use system calls but if there is not other way I think I'll use the "file -i file_name.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you've got execution rights and want to use a "hacky" solution, you can simply do what you've already done (using `file -i path` with `shell_exec`):

```
<?php
    function shell_get_mime_type($path) {
        if (is_readable($path)) {
            $command = 'file -i "' . realpath($path) . '"';

            $shellOutput = trim(shell_exec($command));
            //eg. "nav_item.png: image/png; charset=binary"

            if (!empty($shellOutput)) {
                $colonPosition = strpos($shellOutput, ':');

                if ($colonPosition !== false) {
                    return rtrim(substr($shellOutput, $colonPosition + 1));
                }

                return $shellOutput;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use function [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mime-content-type.php).

Comment: *This function has been deprecated as the PECL extension Fileinfo provides the same functionality (and more) in a much cleaner way.*.

Comment: Yes, this is why I am not using it. Thanks anyway

Comment: the mime_content_type() function (that I don't want to use) gives the correct output, so what is wrong in my code?